# oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, rest-api, webapi

Hello Magento Community,

I am trying to integrate the Magento Rest API in my App. But while doing the OAuth authentication for request token I am getting error as Consumer Key has Expired. I have read on different forums that we need to increase the time. So I did that but still getting the same error.

Is this the issue with Magento Rest API or something wrong with my code. Below is the code I am using for authentication.

```
string ConsumerKey = "13ijbmvmimljnwrs0v929nnc4mh20nc9";
            string ConsumerSecret = "mdb87wcr6ir50s5t4p8fwwxfuwyhfvl7";    
            string StoreBaseURL = "http://www.mymagento.com";

            var authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
            authenticator.SignatureMethod = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1;
            RestClient rClient = new RestClient(StoreBaseURL)
            {
                Authenticator = authenticator
            }; ;
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/oauth/token/request", Method.POST);
            IRestResponse d = rClient.Execute(request);
```

Thanks